# Complex sorting of XML subnodes in .Net3.5 onwards

Tags: xml, .net-3.5, linq-to-xml

XML structure expressed in Xpath kind of

```
Records/Record/Actions/Action/ActionDate
```

the other node on the same level

```
Records/Record/Actions/Action/CTCDate
```

Is there easy or not easy way to sort it on "order by ActionDate,CTCDate" ( in SQL notation ), but per Actions for each selected Record ( not per XML file ) when we iterate somehow and generate sorted XML. File around 50M

Input

```
  <Record>
    <Name>Zywocinski, Cynthia A.</Name>
    <Classification>Individual</Classification>
    <CTType>Reciprocal</CTType>
    <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <City>Lancaster</City>
        <ZIP>01523</ZIP>
        <Province/>
        <State>MA</State>
        <DUNS/>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <References>
      <Reference>Zywocinski-White, Cynthia</Reference>
    </References>
    <Actions>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>13-Oct-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>Z1</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>HHS</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Jul-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>13-Oct-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>A1</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>HHS</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Jul-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>20-Jul-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>R</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>OPM</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Oct-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
    </Actions>
    <Description/>
    <AgencyIdentifiers/>
  </Record>
```

Output

```
  <Record>
    <Name>Zywocinski, Cynthia A.</Name>
    <Classification>Individual</Classification>
    <CTType>Reciprocal</CTType>
    <Addresses>
      <Address>
        <City>Lancaster</City>
        <ZIP>01523</ZIP>
        <Province/>
        <State>MA</State>
        <DUNS/>
      </Address>
    </Addresses>
    <References>
      <Reference>Zywocinski-White, Cynthia</Reference>
    </References>
    <Actions>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>20-Jul-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>R</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>OPM</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Oct-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>13-Oct-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>A1</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>HHS</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Jul-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
     <Action>
       <ActionDate>13-Oct-1999</ActionDate>
       <TermDate>Indef.</TermDate>
       <CTCode>Z1</CTCode>
       <AgencyComponent>HHS</AgencyComponent>
       <EPLSCreateDate>29-Jul-1999</EPLSCreateDate>
     </Action>
    </Actions>
    <Description/>
    <AgencyIdentifiers/>
  </Record>
```

Comment: Looks like you might need to provide more info in order to get some answers. Could you post a small example of your xml? Maybe just 2 or 3 Record notes. Then also list how you want the output sorted.

Comment: @Dennis, I edited original question and provided an example. C# is preferable.